# Problem with getting JSON to android app, propably problem with url

Tags: java, android, json, flickr

I think i did something wrong with string named "url", but im not sure what should i change, what am i doing wrong?

I didn't want to share my api key, normally it is there.
I use no commercial version of flickr.

Main activity:

```
                    FlickrFetchr flickrFetchr = new FlickrFetchr();
                    Log.d("HTTP_JSON",flickrFetchr.getJSONString());
```

JsonString is always "sth went wrong"

FlickrFetchr class:

```
public class FlickrFetchr {

    String API_KEY = "MY_API";
    HttpsURLConnection connection;

    public byte[] getUrlBytes(String urlSpec)
    {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlSpec);
           connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            InputStream imput = connection.getInputStream();

            if(connection.getResponseCode() != HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                throw new Exception();
            }

            int bytesRead;
            byte [] buffer = new byte[1024] ;

            do {
                bytesRead = imput.read(buffer);
                out.write(buffer,0,bytesRead);

            }while (imput.read(buffer)>0);

                out.close();

            return out.toByteArray();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("HTTPeerpr", e.getMessage());
            byte[] emptyArray = new byte[0];
            return emptyArray;
        }
        finally {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }

   public String getURLString(String urlSpec)
    {
        return  getUrlBytes(urlSpec).toString();
    }

    public String getJSONString()
    {
        String jsonString = "sth went wrong";
        try {
            String url = Uri.parse("https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/")
                    .buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter("method", "flickr.photos.getRecent")
                    .appendQueryParameter("api key", API_KEY)
                    .appendQueryParameter("format", "json")
                    .appendQueryParameter("nojsoncallback", "1")
                    .appendQueryParameter("extras", "url_s")
                    .build().toString();

            jsonString = getURLString(url);

        }catch (Exception je)
        {
            Log.e("JSON_ERROR", je.getMessage());
        }
            return jsonString;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: maybe using a library already tested and working fine?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: for example, use https://github.com/boncey/Flickr4Java